# Odoo : write method is only invoked when updating a model

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, erp

Inside a model which I have created, I implemented the write method to update another model fields , so I want to invoke this operation on every record creation but apparently Odoo invokes the method only when updating the record.

Here it is an excerpt from  the model:

```
class formulaire_evaluation(models.Model):
     _name = 'pncevaluation.fe'
     _description = u"Formulaire d\'évaluation"
     name = fields.Char(u"Intitulé du formulaire")
     contributeur = fields.Many2one('pncevaluation.contributeur',string="Contributeur")
     date = fields.Date(u"Date")


     @api.multi
     def write(self, vals):
        rec = super(formulaire_evaluation, self).write(vals)
        #my_custom_code
        return rec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of record creation, Odoo calls ORM *create()* method. So in your case we need to override create() method.

For example:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(formulaire_evaluation, self).create(vals)
    #### your logic to update another model
    return res
```

For more details [Odoo's ORM methods](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods)

NOTE:

If you want to do this operation only at record creation then go with *create()* method and remove *write()* method. Otherwise go with both methods *create()* and *write()*.